# How to split one big json file into smaller multiple files?

Tags: python, json

I have a huge json file with below contents in it. To make it simpler, I removed bunch of things to make it easier to understand. I have a `templates` json array which has bunch of json objects in it.

```
{
  "templates": [
    {
     "clientId": 1234,
     "key1": "value1",
     ...
    },
    {
     "clientId": 9876,
     "key2": "value2",
     ...
    },
    {
     "textGroup": 87,
     "key3": "value3",
     ...
    },
    {
     "textGroup": 90,
     "key4": "value4",
     ...
    }
  ]
}
```

Now I want to read this one big json file and split them into smaller multiple json files. Total number of smaller files will be total number of json objects inside `templates`. As you can see I have two `clientId` json object and two `textGroup` json object so total number of smaller json files generated will be 4.

Each json object is a different file name with content as value of json object. Below is how each file should be generated.

**File name should be:**

```
processConfig-client-1234.json
```

**Content in that file:**

```
{
  "templates": [
    {
     "clientId": 1234,
     "key1": "value1",
     ...
    }
   ]
}
```

similarly for others:

```
processConfig-client-9876.json

{
  "templates": [
    {
     "clientId": 9876,
     "key2": "value2",
     ...
    }
   ]
}

processConfig-textGroup-87.json

{
  "templates": [
    {
     "textGroup": 87,
     "key3": "value3",
     ...
    }
   ]
}

processConfig-textGroup-90.json

{
  "templates": [
    {
     "textGroup": 90,
     "key4": "value4",
     ...
    }
   ]
}
```

File name will always have `processConfig-` followed by either `client-` or `textGroup-` and then followed by the value of that key.

Is this possible to do by any chance?

Comment: Yes, it's possible, but currently this question looks as though you are asking for someone to write code to your specification. Please share your own attempt and ask a specific question about it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Split JSON file in equal/smaller parts with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17640919/split-json-file-in-equal-smaller-parts-with-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import json
dct = json.load('inputfile.json')
for subdct in dct['templates']:
    if "textGroup" in subdct:
        fname = "processConfig-textGroup-{}.json".format(subdct["textGroup"])
    elif "clientId" in subdct:
        fname = "processConfig-client-{}.json".format(subdct["clientId"])
    with open(fname, 'w') as f:
        json.dump({'templates': [subdct]}, f)
```

Of course, if your file is really **huge** (too big to fit into memory) this won't work.

Comment: @JDo then apparently you're doing something wrong (sorry, can't be more specific than you).